# how to create a list of lists from one list using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I do this multiple times every frame in my game. So looking for a way not to loop multiple times.
Thanks for taking a look :)

```
    List<Vector3> listVectors = new List<Vector3>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
        listVectors.Add(new Vector3(i,i,i));
    }

    var listX = from v in listVectors select v.x;
    var listY = from v in listVectors select v.y;
    var listZ = from v in listVectors select v.z;

    // Is it possible to create this without looping multiple times
    List<IEnumerable<float>> listV = new List<IEnumerable<float>>{listX,listY,listZ};
```

Comment: I think you are going to need to clarify *what* you are trying to do. What does the final expected output look like?

Comment: could someone please vote up @spender s answer, cheers nick :)

Comment: @GrantWinney thanks, i need more rep :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<List<float>> lists = listVectors
    .SelectMany(v => new[]{
        new{k = 'x', v = v.x},
        new{k = 'y', v = v.y},
        new{k = 'z', v = v.z}})
    .GroupBy(x => x.k)
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.v).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: @nick Chances are that your original approach is several times more efficient, because it does not require creating transient objects in quantities exceeding the size of your vector by a factor of three, only to throw them away after the list of lists is constructed.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thanks for the heads up, this answer looked the easiest to do. i've just modified it to build a float[][], so whats creating extra? and can I avoid it using this method

Comment: @nick Creation of extra objects (i.e. the `new{k = ..., v = ...}`) is at the heart of this method. There are three anonymous objects plus a three-element array that are created per each `Vector3` object. These anonymous objects are used for "tagging" the individual vector components, so that you could pull them apart later on using `GroupBy`. All of this looks expensive compared to your approach. On the other hand, it is also a single-statement solution, so if the performance is OK with you, there is no reason to change it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Appreciate the explanation :), yea I should refocus on the main areas of performance bottleneck, and this doesn't compare with my current performance problem, calculating curve normals

Answer (score 1):

Since you are producing three different results, you would need to write a loop yourself:

```
List<float> listX = new List<float>(listVectors.Count);
List<float> listY = new List<float>(listVectors.Count);
List<float> listZ = new List<float>(listVectors.Count);
foreach (var vec in listVectors) {
    listX.Add(vec.x);
    listY.Add(vec.y);
    listZ.Add(vec.z);
}
```

You could potentially do that with `List<T>.ForEach` with side effects, but that would be the same thing:

```
listVectors.ForEach(vec => {
    listX.Add(vec.x);
    listY.Add(vec.y);
    listZ.Add(vec.z);
});
```

Of course the best thing would be to avoid copying altogether. You could do it with a simple trick that passes a list of `Vector3` objects along with the "extraction" functor, like this: instead of

```
void Process(IList<float> data) {
    foreach (float f in data) {
        // Do something with f
    }
}
```

and calling it

```
Process(listX);
```

you write

```
void Process(IList<Vector3> data, Func<Vector3,float> extract) {
    foreach (Vector3 v in data) {
        float f = extract(v);
        // Do something with f
    }
}
```

and call

```
Process(listVectors, v => v.x);
```